# Pick background color on click

Tags: jquery

If I have a div with an inline style specifying background color, how do I get the color value on click w/ jQuery?

```
$(".myDiv").click(function(){
   var myColor = $(this)....
});

<div class="myDiv" style="background-color:#8080C0"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).css('background-color')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/eWWXT/